# How can I filter dropdown list to show certain values at the top of the list?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So I have a dropdownlist with list of nationalities and I want to show certain nationalities at the top of the list (since they're the most common ones in that country). How can I do that?

Here's my dropdownlist:

```
<select [ngModel]="null" formControlName="nationality" required >
            <option value="null" disabled selected>{{'SelectNationality' | translate}}</option>
            <option *ngFor="let nationality of nationalities">{{nationality._nationalityKey}}</option>
        </select>
```

E.g. I want the nationality Japanese and Chinese at the top of the list instead of Afgdan and American which would be the top normally.

How can I filter it so that e.g. the list looks like this:

```
Chinese, Japanese, Afgan, American.
```

instead of this:

```
Afgan, American, Chinese, Japanese
```

EDIT 1st attempt:

```
if (this.nationalities.indexOf('Japanese') > 0) {
  this.nationalities.splice(this.nationalities.indexOf('Japanese'), 1);
  this.nationalities.unshift('Japanese');
  }

if (this.nationalities.indexOf('Chinese') > 0) {
  this.nationalities.splice(this.nationalities.indexOf('Chinese'), 1);
  this.nationalities.unshift('Chinese');
  }
```

Unfortunately, this is redundant code and it only works for when I initially initialize an array. If I populate an array with data from the server, it no longer works. Why and how can I make the above code better?

Comment: Investigate the use of Pipes in Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to split merge your array :

```
const mostPopularNationalities = ['Japanese', 'Chinese'];
const otherNationalities = this.nationalities
.filter(nationality => !mostPopularNationalities.includes(nationality));
this.nationalities = {...mostPopularNationalities, ...otherNationalities};
```

Comment: Sorry that might not work because of the datatype of my nationalities. The data from the service looks like this: [{"_nationalityKey":"Afghan"},{"_nationalityKey":"American"}, etc...]

Comment: Then why don't you just start by : `this.nationalities = this.nationalities.map( n => n._nationalityKey)` ?

Comment: Not sure but that code snippet is still breaking the binding to my control. I will have to debug.

Comment: With your transformation, the end result is like this: {"0":"Afghan"}.... when I do the binding, it should be nationality.value or..? How do I make sure I get the correct value?

Comment: Here I made a stackblitz with a running code, you can edit it if you want to example better what you want : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49661714

Answer (score 0):

In html:

```
<form action="exampleaction">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="english">
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="african">
  <input type="submit" value="chinesse">
</form>
```

In javascript:

```
var positions_one = [];
var positions_two = [];
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i in x) {
    if(x[i].value.includes("chinesse")) {
        positions_one.push(x[i]);
    }
    if(x[i].value.includes("english")) {
        positions_two.push(x[i]);
    }
}
```

try this, this is a similar example...

for a null values use this filter...

```
if(x[i].value !== null || x[i].value !== undefined) { not do nothing};
```

Comment: I don't want to drop the items, I just want to position some items at the top. let me edit post to example further. Please see edited post @Help

Comment: Oh, then u want positioning the by filter per filter?, example: filter_a position one, filter_b position 3?

Comment: filter dropdown to position certain elements. Let's make the filter Japanese and Chinese to be at the top of the list instead of alphabetically Afgan and American. Does that make sense? Just like in the example I showed.

Comment: @hello, why is there position_one and position_two arrays? Why two arrays and how will I bind to them in the html?